# Как создать погрузку постов на AJAX в шаблоне страницы в WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ajax

Можно ли создать подгрузку страницы по кнопке через AJAX в шаблоне страницы (page) в WordPress. Понял как туда прикрутить пагинацию, но она перезагружает страницу. На странице несколько категорий с выводом постов, и нужно чтоб они не конфликтовали.
Каждую категорию вывожу так:

```
<?php               
if ( have_posts() ) : // если имеются записи в блоге.
    query_posts('cat=220');   // указываем ID рубрик, которые необходимо вывести.
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();  // запускаем цикл обхода материалов блога

?>

        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'medium' ) ?>" id="<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>" > 

<?php
    endwhile;  // завершаем цикл.
endif;
/* Сбрасываем настройки цикла. Если ниже по коду будет идти еще один цикл, чтобы не было сбоя. */
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Ну наверное приведите весь код, вместе с JS и как Вы хендлите аякс запрос на бекенде, потому что, ну есть у Вас цикл с выводом постов, это особо ничего не говорит.

Comment: Так у меня нечего и нет, с AJAX я вообще не дружу, поэтому и не могу это сделать